# How to map string values into integer starting from one to number of strings

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have a list of integers as below:

```
['#a1', '#a1', '#a5', '#a5', '#b3', '#b3', '#b3', '#b6', '#b6']
```

I want to convert it into a list of integers (starting from 1) as below:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Value of strings are not important. I want to convert similar strings into one integer value (starting from one).

Please let me know your idea how to implement in python.

Comment: There is no `2/4` in the original list?

Comment: Please provide more information on how you would like to perform this mapping. Why is `'#a1'` = `1`?

Comment: Why is it closed, it is quite clear what op wants? Numbering different elements starting by 1...

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM , No there is not. Order of data is not important. I just want to start from integer value "1".

Comment: @M Z, value of string is not important. I want to convert similar strings into one integer value.

Comment: @user_na, Sure, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `itertools.groupby` with `enumerate`.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['#a1', '#a1', '#a5', '#a5', '#b3', '#b3', '#b3', '#b6', '#b6']

result = [idx for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(groupby(data), 1) for i in v]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

---

Even though you can use `itertools` for that, this requirement is so simple that you could easily implement it without loading any additional module.

This could be a good exercise to learn about generator function, so it would be lazily evaluated on iteration:

```
def fun(arr):
    i = 0
    last = {}
    for a in arr:
        if a != last: i+= 1
        last = a
        yield i
```

And use it like this:

```
result = [*fun(x)]
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: It could be easily implemented without `itertools`. It would be a good exercise for OP to learn about generator functions.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what * do in : "[*fun(x)]".